# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<>'

Tags: asp.net-core, collections

I cannot seem to get past this error in my ASP.net Core 6 API web app.

My `httpget()`

```
 // GET: api/Shippingschedules/shipname
        [HttpGet("{shipname}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Shippingschedule>> GetShippingSchedulesByShip(string shipname)
        {
            ActionResult<Shippingschedule> Shippingschedule = await _context.Shippingschedules.Where(
                x => x.Text.Contains(shipname)).ToListAsync(); //.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (Shippingschedule == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Shippingschedule;
        }
```

But if replace the `ToListAsync()` to the `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`, it compiles. Why?

I am trying to bring back all the records it finds, not just the first one. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` works because it returns only one record where as `ToListAsync()` returns a collection of the record.

Change the `ActionResult<Shippingschedule>` to `IEnumerable<ShippingSchedule>` and the `.ToListAsync()` should work. Also, change the return type of api from `Task<ActionResult<Shippingschedule>>` to `Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shippingschedule>>>`

```cs
        [HttpGet("{shipname}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Shippingschedule>>> GetShippingSchedulesByShip(string shipname)
        {
            IEnumerable<ShippingSchedule> Shippingschedule = await _context.Shippingschedules.Where(
                x => x.Text.Contains(shipname)).ToListAsync(); //.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (Shippingschedule == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Shippingschedule;
        }
```